# Working with nested selectors & vuejs css modules

Tags: css, vue.js, module

Is it possible to work with nested css selectors when using [vuejs css modules](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html)?

For example, I want to scope this css (so that id **does not affect child components**):

```
.list {
    ...

    .item {
       ...
     }
}
```

In the documentation I could see only not-nested examples, but is it at all convenient, since I'll need then name them like `.list-item` which resembles BEM. But if I use BEM there is no point in using css modules, is there?

Comment: this looks like a combination of `scss` and `scoped`?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's possible to work with nested css selectors so they will not affect child components; use css modules.

You need to use a preprocessor to enable nesting, either [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/).

If using [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) your component would look something like this

```vue
<template>
  <ul :class="$style.list">
    <li :class="$style.item"></li>
  </ul>
</template>

<!--       Or lang="less" -->
<style module lang="scss">
.list {
    ...

    .item {
       ...
     }
}
</style>
```

Comment: How can you use the $style. in class? I tried to used that but the class name doesn't appear when render.

Comment: @user3779015 Have you added `module` to the `<style>` tag?

Comment: Yes, this is my style - <style module lang="scss">. Did you do any configuration on webpack? cuz it seems like when I used the lang="scss", i cannot used the $style in class.

Comment: As the OP referenced the [vue loader docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html) it seemed unncessary to point out that this should be configured beforehand :-)

Comment: I was wondering if you can help me with my webpack config? I tried to add the configs from vue-loader website but it didn't work. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55350951/laravel-mix-configuration-for-vue-loader) of my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, nesting css selectors is called using scss. You will have to setup scss.

Example make your style tag in the vue component:

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
```

The scoped attribute tells it to apply only to this component.

In regards to bem you can do stuff like this in scss:

```
.list {
   //styles-a

   &-item {
      //styles-b
   }
}
```

which will convert to this in css:

```
.list {
    //styles-a
}
.list-item {
    //styles-b
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't take into account that OP asked about CSS Modules (`<style module lang="scss">`)

Answer (score 1):

If you want, for example, override CSS class of some UI library in Vue you can use `:global` keyword. Let's say you have a `n-dropdown` component from Naive UI library. And you want to customize it with overriding its native very deeeeeply nested `n-dropdown-option-body__prefix--show-icon` CSS class **only in current component** using CSS modules. Here is how you can do it:

```
<template>
    <n-dropdown :class="$style.menu">
    </n-dropdown>
</template>

<style module>
.menu:global.n-dropdown-menu .n-dropdown-option .n-dropdown-option-body .n-dropdown-option-body__prefix.n-dropdown-option-body__prefix--show-icon {
    margin-left: 33px;
    margin-right: 19px;
}
</style>
```

In the end you will get selector which looks something like this

```
.MobileNavMenu_menu_NhSka.n-dropdown-menu .n-dropdown-option .n-dropdown-option-body .n-dropdown-option-body__prefix.n-dropdown-option-body__prefix--show-icon {
    margin-left: 33px;
    margin-right: 19px;
}
```

So all classes after `:global` keyword will be untouched by `module` manipulations.
If `.n-dropdown-menu` should be a child of `menu` then `:global` should have a whitespace from both sides:
`.menu :global .n-dropdown-menu`
Vue will remind you about it with horrible crash